# ASRock J4105-ITX motherboard is not booting with Marvell RAID card installed

Tags: linux, raid, mini-itx

I guess it happens as RAID has legacy BIOS and the motherboard is UEFI only?

I can't find CSM in the BIOS either.

Is there a way to fix it?

Not a big deal as I can use Linux's RAID but recover & copy data from old RAID is pita.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to boot from an OS stores in the raid array? If you have a spare drive (or even just a USB), you could try booting into a separate (uefi) Linux environment, and then access your raid device from there.